# Concatenating Fields where Values Match in other Field using ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

Is there a way in ArcGIS Field Calculator to concatenate fields from a column if values match in another column?

I have attached an image for reference.

[image]

Comment: How big a concatenation will you expect? Looks like in your example 4 three's? But could it be millions? Need more detail as @Midavalo suggest? Amend your question.

Comment: The operation you want to perform requires operations across multiple rows. I don't think this is possible in the Field Calculator without writing Python or VB scripting code using a search cursor or something similar.

Comment: As @Llaves wrode, it shouldn't be possible to solve the task using the Field Calculator. You would Need a search cursor to read the values and in a second step a update cursor to write the values to your "Join" field.

Comment: I found a link to a tool that does exactly what I was asking and showing in the example image that I attached. http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=52dfcef46fdb4c76bfbc08dc01570f3c

Comment: @Saleika It is quite possible using the Field Calculator.  You can perform a lot of python tasks directly in the Field Calculator codeblock.

Answer (score 3):

If your concatenation isn't going to be huge (just a handful of values rather than hundreds, or millions as Hornbydd queried) then this is quite doable in the Field Calculator.  Select the Python parser, and check the "Show Codeblock" box.

In Pre-logic Script Code:

```py
mydict = dict()
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('testPoint',['NameField','ValueField','JoinField']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        mydict.setdefault(row[0],[]).append(str(row[1]))

def concat(nf):
    x = None
    if nf in mydict:
        x = ",".join(mydict[nf])
    return x
```

Replacing `testPoint` with the name of your layer, and `['NameField','ValueField','JoinField']` with a list of your three fields

And in the expression:

```py
concat(!NameField!)
```

Where `NameField` is the field that holds the key values.

In the first part of the Pre-logic script code, a Search Cursor is used to find all the values in the `NameField` and `ValueField` fields, and creating a python dictionary to store those values.  Then in the function `concat()` the Field Calculator updates the `JoinField` with the values from the dictionary.

Here is the code in the Field Calculator window:

[image]

And the output result in the attribute table:

[image]

Note that this does not require the key values in `NameField` to be in order - you will see there is a `1` in row 13 and a couple of `2` values in rows 17 & 18.

Comment: Thank you for the response Midavalo. Very impressive ! I'll be using this in the near future. Much appreciated!

Comment: Is there a similar solution for QGIS? I'm stacked with the same problem...